# Split audio from different applications to different audio outputs

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth

I'd like to be able to have audio from 2 different applications go to 2 different audio outputs (say speakers from line out, and bluetooth audio headset). Is this possible on OSX 10.11.6 through standard system prefs or an external audio manager or something? Cheers.

Comment: I like your username. Don't deviate that septum. Moving on ... please be a tad more detailed about the apps you need to use, and most importantly _what steps you have taken to figure this out for your self_, but have failed or have only been partially successful. I've heard (pun intended) that [Soundflower](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) has some wicked good audio magic. Never used it myself. Neither do I have any financial stake in the Rogue Amoeba company/organization/hive-mind.

Comment: Steps to figure this out for myself? Googled for 5 minutes - unable to find a direct answer, posting on stackexchange was the next logical step.

I checked out soundflower but wasn't sure it would solve my issue.

I'd say being able to route audio from google chrome to my bluetooth audio sink and spotify to my line out would be ideal.

Comment: Septum is well deviated. It's the price I pay for the fear and intimidation powers that come with having an aggressive sneeze.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I direct audio from a single app to a particular output?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26568/can-i-direct-audio-from-a-single-app-to-a-particular-output)

Answer (score 2):

As @IconDaemon says, your two potentials are [Rogue Amoeba](https://www.rogueamoeba.com) & Soundflower, paid or free.
Personally I don't trust [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/) any more, it started to get very crashy around Mavericks & I've not really touched it since.
It was made by Cycling74, then given to Rogue Amoeba to host, but they've long abandoned it so its maintenance has been from whoever posts the most recent re-write.

Rogue Amoeba have 2 apps, one that records, Audio Hijack $49, one that just routes, Loopback $99. I've not really played with Loopback but Audio Hijack already can do most routings.

I made some pretty pictures of possible routings using Audio Hijack on this answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/203009/85275

A third choice is [Plogue Bidule](https://www.plogue.com/products/bidule/) - which I just found overkill & never really spent the time to learn it